# XSLT 1.0 group on multiple values

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

My XML is structured like this (simplified)

```
    <Record>
        <Person>
            <name>Jim</name>
            <year>
                <value>2022</value>
            </year>
        </Person>
    </Record>
    <Record>
        <Person>
            <name>Mary</name>
            <year>
                <value>2022</value>
                <value>2023</value>
            </year>
        </Person>
    </Record>    
    <Record>
        <Person>
            <name>Linda</name>
            <year>
                <value>2022</value>
                <value>2021</value>
            </year>
        </Person>
    </Record>
```

I need to create an HTML list grouped by year/value which can be shared across Person records.

```
2023
-Mary

2022
-Jim
-Linda
-Mary

2021
-Linda
```

I have tried standard Meunchian grouping, but all I get is the first year/value

```
2022
-Jim
-Linda
-Mary
```

XSLT

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0"
    xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common">
    
    <xsl:key match="Person" name="person-year" use="year/value"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="Record">

        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="Record">
        <xsl:for-each select="Person[generate-id(.)=generate-id(key('person-year', year/value))]">
            <table class="table table-striped table-bordered" summary="list of {year/value} people">
                <tr>
                    <th>
                        <xsl:value-of select="year/value"/>
                    </th>
                </tr>
                <xsl:for-each select="key('person-year', year/value)">
                    <xsl:sort order="ascending" select="name"/>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <a href="{link}" target="_blank">
                                <xsl:value-of select="name"/>
                            </a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </table>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to group every `Person` by `year/value` so you first need to know what all the `year/value` values are. You can add another `xsl:key` for this.

Then you process all of the years and use the current year to access your original key to get the people for that year.

Example...

**XML** (updated to be well-formed)

```xml
<doc>
    <Record>
        <Person>
            <name>Jim</name>
            <year>
                <value>2022</value>
            </year>
        </Person>
    </Record>
    <Record>
        <Person>
            <name>Mary</name>
            <year>
                <value>2022</value>
                <value>2023</value>
            </year>
        </Person>
    </Record>
    <Record>
        <Person>
            <name>Linda</name>
            <year>
                <value>2022</value>
                <value>2021</value>
            </year>
        </Person>
    </Record>
</doc>
```

**XSLT 1.0**

```xml
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    
    <xsl:key name="years" match="Person/year/value" use="."/>
    <xsl:key name="person-year" match="Person" use="year/value"/>
        
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:for-each select=".//Record/Person/year/value[generate-id()=generate-id(key('years',.)[1])]">
            <xsl:sort select="." order="descending"/>
            <table class="table table-striped table-bordered" summary="list of {.} people">
                <tr>
                    <th>
                        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                    </th>
                </tr>
                <xsl:for-each select="key('person-year', .)">
                    <xsl:sort order="ascending" select="name"/>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <a href="{link}" target="_blank">
                                <xsl:value-of select="name"/>
                            </a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </table>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output** (@href is empty because your source didn't have `link` elements)

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered" summary="list of 2023 people">
   <tr>
      <th>2023</th>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>
         <a href="" target="_blank">Mary</a>
      </td>
   </tr>
</table>
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered" summary="list of 2022 people">
   <tr>
      <th>2022</th>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>
         <a href="" target="_blank">Jim</a>
      </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>
         <a href="" target="_blank">Linda</a>
      </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>
         <a href="" target="_blank">Mary</a>
      </td>
   </tr>
</table>
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered" summary="list of 2021 people">
   <tr>
      <th>2021</th>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>
         <a href="" target="_blank">Linda</a>
      </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```